# How to read object back from dropdown

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using JavaScript.

I make an api call to get a list of class objects (asp.net mvc c#).

I enumerate through this list in JavaScript and set and add items to my dropdown.

When I click a button I want to get the selected item and parse/read/cast back the class object but I get an undefinded error.

This is my model:

```
public  class SubscriptionLookUp
{
    public string SubscriptionType { get; set; }
    public int SubscriptionTypeId { get; set; }
    public double UnitCost { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

This is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://mydomain/SubscriptionLookUp?currentSubscription"
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    success: function (data) {
          $("#cboAvailableSubscriptions").empty();
        $("#cboAvailableSubscriptions").append($("<option></option>").val('').html('Please Select'));
        $.each(data, function (key, item) {

            if (item.ErrorMessage !== '' && item.ErrorMessage!==null) {
                $('#divError').html('Server Error');
                return;
            }
            $("#cboAvailableSubscriptions").append($("<option></option>").val(item).html(item.SubscriptionType));
        })                                    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          $("#divError").html('Server Error');
    }
});
```

Which is populated just fine and this is my final bit to read teh object back:

```
$('#divChange').click(function () {

    var SubscriptionLookUp = {
        SubscriptionType: '',
        SubscriptionTypeId: '',
        UnitCost: '',
    };
    SubscriptionLookUp = $("#cboAvailableSubscriptions").val();

    alert(SubscriptionLookUp.SubscriptionType);
});
```

The alert returns undefined...

Comment: ``alert(SubscriptionLookUp)`` will give you the value

Comment: @EhsanSajjad thanks for your comment but that will  return the whole object. i am trying to read the property from that object

Comment: you have to construct your object your self

Comment: ``SubscriptionLookUp.SubscriptionType = $("#cboAvailableSubscriptions").val()``

Comment: @EhsanSajjad thanks but that did not work.  Just to confirm the 'item' i am adding is the class object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.val()` uses `Object.prototype.toString.call(value)`, which is converting your `item` to the string `[Object object]` (you can see this by viewing the source of your generated html). So, when trying to read the property `SubscriptionType`, JavaScript is referencing the `String.prototype`, not your `item` -therefore `undefined`.

With little change to your code, you could use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`:

`Writer`

```
$("#cboAvailableSubscriptions").append(
  $("<option></option>").val(JSON.stringify(item))
                        .html(item.SubscriptionType)
);
```

`Reader`

```
SubscriptionLookUp = JSON.parse($("#cboAvailableSubscriptions").val());
```

You may want to look into [`$.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/), seems like the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) instead of val():

```
$("#cboAvailableSubscriptions").append($("<option></option>").data("itemKey", item).html(item.SubscriptionType));
```

And to retrieve it:

```
$('#divChange').click(function () {

    var SubscriptionLookUp = {
        SubscriptionType: '',
        SubscriptionTypeId: '',
        UnitCost: '',
    };
    SubscriptionLookUp = $("#cboAvailableSubscriptions").find(":selected").data("itemKey");

    alert(SubscriptionLookUp.SubscriptionType);
});
```